# After upgrade to 2011, Component's metadata field not getting loaded for specific schema in IE

Tags: 2011, upgrade, 5.3

After upgrading from 5.3 to 2011, for one specific schema, some of the metadata fields is not getting loaded  in IE 9 and above. It just shows the field description or Label, but the actual field value area is not available.

Is there any patch available for this issue?

Here is an example of some of the schema XML that is failing

```
<xsd:element name="meta_language" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="category:meta_languages">
     <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
             <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"></tcm:ExtensionXml>
             <tcm:Size xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">1</tcm:Size>
             <tcm:listtype xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">select</tcm:listtype>
        </xsd:appinfo>
     </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

Adding Image that might help.Here the Language field input area is not getting loaded[image: here the Language field input area is not getting loaded]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. Maybe you could post an example of your Schema XML for one of the fields that doesn't work.

Comment: Pawan - I have updated your answer with the code and added a couple of tags to make it a bit clearer. Next time you can use the edit functionality to add the code yourself. Unfortunately I don't know the answer!

Comment: Since you have provided the schema XML which are NOT failing; Can you also share the schema XML that is failing?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, the XML I have provided above is of the metadata field for which the input area is not getting loaded. The NOT is added by mistake.

Comment: I've seen this in my version of Tridion. If I remember correctly it occurs when there are special characters in the field (like `&`) but don't quote me on that. If I see it again I'll post back with an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to all for responding, got this issue fixed by installing the **Hotfix Rollup SDLTridion2011SP1HR#2**.